# Draw Window Background with a Canvas-Based Activity

Tags: android, background, android-layout

So [I figured out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837889/android-setting-window-background-on-launched-activity) the proper way to set the Activities background, so that I could show a 'fake' background image to the user while the Activity loaded, per [this blog post by Romain Guy](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html).  I can verify this works by loading a test layout on the launched Activity, so I know the background image is being set.

My issue is this: I have a ListView that launches an Activity that can take up to 5 seconds (in fairly rare cases) to draw several shapes to a custom View via a canvas and onDraw.  When the user selects an item from the ListView, the screen simply sits there showing the ListView, waiting for the 2 - 5 seconds while the drawing is taking place.  Some details:

XML of the Activity, canvas_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.package.name.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In the Activity onCreate(), I inflate the above XML, and in onResume(), I initiate the drawing method that writes to the custom CanvasView:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    mCanvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    .
    .
    .
    doDrawing();
}
```

doDrawing() sends data to the CanvasView class, and triggers that classes onDraw.

So, my feeling is that the Activities' View isn't being shown because the canvas drawing is using the UI thread... I tried moving the drawing to onResume, hoping that the Activity would draw the layout inflated in onCreate first BEFORE onResume was called, but no dice.  What I'd like to happen is:

1. User clicks on ListView item
2. Activity gets launched, showing the 'fake' background image
3. Activity draws to canvas
4. Canvas draws to View, displaying it to the user

What is happening:

1. User clicks on ListView item
2. Screen sits there on ListView while activity draws to canvas
3. View with drawn canvas is displayed to user

I had also thought about using an AsyncTask to do the drawing, and maybe that is the right solution here, but trying to keep this as simple as possible as there is really only a delay for very large drawing sets, which I expect to be fairly rare.

Thanks,

Paul

EDIT:

Per Romain's question, some details on doDrawing().  doDrawing() opens an XML file, reads in some data that describe various path shapes, then sends that data to the CanvasView via a public method, addPath():

```
private final void doDrawing() {
    // open XML file, read data in, package it up into a Path object, path
    {snipped}

    // send the data to the CanvasView via a public method
    mCanvas.addPath(path);
}
```

Now, in the CanvasView, here is the code for addPath():

```
public void addPath(Path path) {
    mPaths.add(path);

// do we need to update the CanvasView?
if (mIsVisible) {
     invalidate();
}
}
```

Finally, in the onDraw method in the CanvasView, onDraw loops through the mPaths ArrayList, writing each of the Paths to the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this issue is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), loading a simple 'splash' view in `onPreExecute()`, calling `doDrawing()` in `doInBackground()`, and then hiding the 'splash' View in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does doDrawing() do? To call a View's onDraw() method, you must pass a Canvas. What Canvas are you using? The only way you can get access to the screen's Canvas is by using the Canvas you receive when draw(Canvas)/dispatchDraw(Canvas)/onDraw(Canvas) are invoked automatically.

Besides, what you are trying to do just won't work. Before drawing views, the system erases the content of the window. You cannot draw into the Canvas only once, you must do it on every frame (every time draw

Comment: I've added code for doDrawing() above.  It processes an XML file, pulls out data that will be represented graphically, and passes it to a CanvasView method.  That method then triggers the ConvasView.onDraw via calling invalidate().

Comment: I am re-drawing the view via onDraw everytime that gets called (orientation changes, etc).