# Customize android splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-theme

I created splash screen for the app using activity theme. That's effective way to display it in loading time, recommended by Google developers (https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/SW7F2CJvAmU).

I created splash.xml in drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/ColorPrimary" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

created theme with it

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

and applied this theme to activity in manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

Now i need to customize my splash screen from code. I need to change bitmap and color, or add another item to layer-list. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Setting Window Background on launched Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837889/android-setting-window-background-on-launched-activity)

Comment: @R.Zagórski This isn't answer to my question. Splash works for me. I need to change it parameters inside layer-list (color, bitmap) programmatically, or maybe use some another solution to have this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to change it parameters inside layer-list (color, bitmap) programmatically

You cannot do that from code because your code is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use a layout(splash.xml) that include an image and use that layout as your contentView in your logical side , you can then use some animation to your image , or changing background.......