# Reduce an Android Hello World Launch Time

Tags: android, performance

I have a hello world app with white screen. No even overridden onCreate with setContentView. So it's just a white screen. No any libraries is added. No support libraries and so on. So it's totally empty, I guess. A theme is not inherited from any standard theme, so, I believe, (but I'm not sure) Android doesn't parse any theme for me.

And it still takes ~220-300ms to start. For me, it's a lot. I mean, it's a lot for a complete empty application I have no idea what to cut off, if I just want a white screen.

What can I turn off from system features or something else to reduce this time to something like ~16ms?

Comment: you can't wait 2 seconds? the compiling takes time and the install of the application too

Comment: are you talking about white screen before launching your main Activity?

Comment: Hi, Enamul! Yes, I am :) But not only. I know that I can change the background color of that screen, just by changing windowBackground, but I also want to sync it with my animation.For some reasons, Android calls onCreate, but, then, makes some heavy calculations, so if we start an animation immediately - we're still in troubles - animation is super laggy even on Nexus5X.

Answer (score 0):

You may reference to this post: [Android: Setting Window Background on launched Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837889/android-setting-window-background-on-launched-activity)

Android need certain of time to initialize application, so what you can do is to override app background with your splash screen. Refer to Google Maps application.

**Edit:**

@Slava, So Zygote on Android needs time to initialize the app. That's why it's recommended to override the window background and show it as some kind of a splash screen.

Zygote creates a VM for every single app, to make sure all the apps are sandbox applications. Read [this article](https://anatomyofandroid.com/2013/10/15/zygote/).

Comment: Thanks, Maciej! :) But I've already done it. But there're still problems with animations :( Heh, and, to be honest, I'm interested - how to decrease the launch time.

Comment: So do you do many different operations on the main screen or the App launch?
Try move everything you can to background thread and let the main thread do the animation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what to move?

Comment: I forgot it's an empty app. So if you launch the app directly from Android Studio it can take more time to actually load. Try to install it from generated apk file. Open a console in Android Studio and run this command: 
`./gradlew clean assembleDebug`
and then the apk will be in .../PROJECT_NAME/app/build/generated/debug.apk
Send it to device and install it.

You will see, that time is much faster than while debugging it.

Comment: I tried to install the file, generated in 'release' mode, I hope, with all optimisations, if they are even possible in one-class app :) I launched it from the launcher of my device. First run is always a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

Add the layout background. And make the background image sit in the

```
drawable-nodpi
```

folder. This will reduce a bit amount of time as the device take cares of the layout size. I have my personal experience in this. For clean experience, use a blank white image from the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But are you sure that it'll accelerate cold launch? I mean, now I don't have any setContentView call. So Android takes some time before calling onCreate.

Comment: Try it mate, it should?